# Want to know which one is better javascript design & clean code as per javascript experts

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs

```
switch (cloudType) {
            case "aws":
                value = (updateDefaultInfo) ? this._resetMessageDefaultValues.aws = defaultValue : this._resetMessageDefaultValues.aws;
                resetText = this._messages.current.aws
                break;
            case "vsphere_on_prem":
                value = (updateDefaultInfo) ? this._resetMessageDefaultValues.private = defaultValue : this._resetMessageDefaultValues.private;
                resetText = this._messages.current.private
                break;
            case "azure":
                value = (updateDefaultInfo) ? this._resetMessageDefaultValues.azure = defaultValue : this._resetMessageDefaultValues.azure;
                resetText = this._messages.current.azure
                break;
        }
```

Or

```
value = (updateDefaultInfo) ? this._resetMessageDefaultValues[cloudType] = defaultValue : this._resetMessageDefaultValues[cloudType];
                    resetText = this._messages.current[cloudType]
```

I am new to javascript world and wanted to learn and design things in better manner.

Comment: "Clean code" is somewhat opinion-based, you might try codereview instead (and probably post more of your code). Neither snippet looks good to me IMO, the first uses `switch` when it should probably use an object indexed by `case`s instead, and the second uses assignment *inside* the conditional operator, which is very confusing.

Comment: Can you please give me one example how I can use object indexed by cases here?

Comment: The question asks for opinion, which is offtopic. But neither of them. Long ternary expressions are unreadable. Why does the question have angular tag? Are you using Angular or React? Because Angular defaults to TypeScript, and things may be different in JS and TS because of type safety.